# OSX and bacula: system backup or malware?

Tags: macos, backup, osx-mavericks

Worrying about the bash "shellshock" bug, I have taken my iMac (running Mac OS Mavericks 10.9.4) off the network and checked for open ports. When I run:

```
netstat -atp tcp
```

…on the terminal, I see an unexpected entry for `*.bacula-fd`, which I never installed.

Is Bacula the back-end of Time Machine, or otherwise part of the OS? Or is it possibly malware?

Comment: Note that "bacula-fd" really just means port #9102. While that port is normally used by bacula, it could actually be anything at all. You can use `sudo lsof -i:9102` to find out more about the process using the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bacula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacula) is a third-party open-source backup tool that's not included with OS X as standard. If you've not installed it then something funny has been going on. But you might have installed it without knowing, as part of the install of some other product.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I guess my next step is searching for products that include it. Or possibly first uninstall everything I don't really use, and then search :-)

Answer (score -2):

I ran sudo lsof -i:9102, and found that Bacula-fd was used by my Wireless Kodak ESP5200 series printer software.  Seems to be a legit process on my system.